# MacBook Pro doesn't wake automatically from sleep when lid is opened

Tags: sleep-wake

I have a pretty recent 13" MBP (2020) currently running Catalina. When the machine is asleep with the lid closed for a while and I come back and open it it does not come out of sleep.

Touching the space bar or other keys doesn't do anything, the only thing that works is pressing the physical (T2) power button. Then it wakes and things generally seem okay.

I'm clearly [not the only one](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252045168) with this problem, but I can't find an answer for whether this is expected behavior, a setting or something wrong?